# Gazebo GUI Not Showing Up when running WSL2 Graphics on Windows 11

Tags: qt5, wsl-2, gazebo-simu, windows-11

I am attempting to use ROS with the Gazebo GUI. I recently upgraded to Windows 11 for the WSL GUI support and have the gedit GUI working. However, when I run the command `$ gazebo`, the GUI does not open.

Running `$ gazebo --verbose` gives the following error messages

```
[Err] [RenderEngine.cc:749] Can't open display: :0

[Err] [GuiIface.cc:124] This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. 

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

After enabling the QT Debug environment variable using export `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` and rerunning the gazebo command with the verbose option set, It shows me

```
[Dbg] [GuiIface.cc:112] Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
[Dbg] [GuiIface.cc:112] QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
[Dbg] [GuiIface.cc:112] loaded library "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
```

I believe that I have all of the necessary packages installed from this output, so I am wondering why gazebo is not showing up. I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling gazebo to no avail.

Thank you so much for your time. If I get this problem sorted out, I will post. Please let me know if any other system/output information is needed.

Other information:
I am not using X Server because the Windows 11 upgrade does not require it for graphical WSL  applications (but did try it with X Server installed just in case)

I have tinkered around with the ~/.bashrc profile. DISPLAY=0:0 option was set, but I deleted  this because Windows 11 did not need it (or so I think?)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

After reading up online, I found this answer to a similar question to mine.

https://superuser.com/questions/1681647/windows-11-wsl-not-opening-gui-in-my-ubuntu-shell

Getting ubuntu and re-installing gazebo on that worked. Now I can open up the Gazebo GUI.